# Move all the digits at the end of string using recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion

My code is giving me output like  #check##done654321
but i want something like "#check##done123456" using recursion. Input String is  replaceD("123#check#456#done").
How do i do it?Is it possible.

```
     public String replaceD(String str){
         String str1 = "";
         String str2 = "";
         if(str.length() == 0){
           return "";
         }
        char ch = str.charAt(0);
        if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
            str1 = str1 + ch;
        }
        else{
           str2 = str2 + ch;
        }
   return str2 + replaceD(str.substring(1))+str1;
 }
```

Comment: `str1 = ch + str1;`

Comment: It would still give the same output.

Comment: What is your input ant expected output? Please post a few more examples.

Comment: For example if the input is "@#34**5".I need output like "@#**345".

Comment: This doesn't seem like a task for recursion. Do you have to use recursion?

Comment: I was told to do it using recursion.

Comment: This can be solved much more efficiently using iteration.

Comment: Is it not possible using recursion?

Comment: The method takes only one parameter as input of type string.like removeD("34gfg").

Comment: The method usingRecursion takes only 1 parameter. You are exposing only this method. The method replaceD_2 is private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Recursion**

```
public static void usingRecursion(String str){
        System.out.println(replaceD_2(str, ""));
    }

    private static String replaceD_2(String str, String str2){
        String str1 = "";

        if(str.length() == 0){
            return str2;
        }
        if(str.charAt(0) >= '0' && str.charAt(0) <= '9'){
            str2 = str2 + str.charAt(0);
        }
        else {
            str1 = str1 + str.charAt(0);
        }
        return str1 + replaceD_2(str.substring(1), str2);
    }
```

**Using Iteration**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = ScannerUtils.scanForString();
        StringBuilder digitBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder charBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i< input.length(); i++){
            if(input.charAt(i) >= '0' && input.charAt(i) <= '9'){
                digitBuilder.append(input.charAt(i));
            }
            else {
                charBuilder.append(input.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        String output = charBuilder.toString().concat(digitBuilder.toString());
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary that the order need to be preserved or is it to be sorted. If it is just the order to be preserved then remove the sorting and add str2 directly.

Code for sorting given below

```
public String replaceD(String str, String str1, String str2){
         String strtemp1="";
         String strtemp2="";

         if(str.length() == 0){
             String k[] = str2.split("");
             Arrays.sort(k)
             str2=""
             for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
                 str2+=k[i];
             }
         return str1+str2;
         }

         char ch = str.charAt(0);
         if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
             str1 = str1 + ch;
         }
         else{
             str2 = str2 + ch;
         } 

    return replaceD(str.substring(1),str1+strtemp1, str2+strtemp2);
    }
```

Comment: Input String is replaceD("12ab45").There is only one parameter as string.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public String replaceD(String str){
         String str1 = "";
         String str2 = "";
         if(str.length() == 0){
           return "";
         }
        int l = str.length();
        char ch = str.charAt(l-1);
        if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
            str1 = str1 + ch;
        }
        else{
           str2 = str2 + ch;
        }
   return replaceD(str.substring(0,l-1))+str2+str1;
 }
```

Comment: will it also give non digit characters in order? For example if the input string is 12ab34.it should give me "ab1234".

Comment: Yes, Since recursion uses stack. always begin from the end to preserve order.

Comment: It would give the same output as input string.